# TypeError while looping through dictionary key and items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, typeerror

I have a dictionary and when I tried to loop through its keys and values, it throws me an error:

> **TypeError: items() takes no arguments (1 given)**

```
BDT_param_grid1 ={"learning_rate": np.arange(0.1,1.0,0.1),
                  "n_estimators": np.arange(1, 1000, 10),
                  "base_estimator__min_samples_split": np.arange(0.1,1.0,0.1),
                  "base_estimator__min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1,60,1),
                  "base_estimator__max_leaf_nodes": np.arange(2,60,1),
                  "base_estimator__min_weight_fraction_leaf": np.arange(0.1, 0.4, 0.1),
                  "base_estimator__max_features": np.arange(0.1,1,0.1),
                  "base_estimator__max_depth": np.arange(1, 28, 1)}

for key,items in dict.items(BDT_param_grid1):
    print(key,items)
```

My expected result is:

```
learning_rate [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
n_estimators [  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91 101 111 121 131 141 151 161 171
 181 191 201 211 221 231 241 251 261 271 281 291 301 311 321 331 341 351
 361 371 381 391 401 411 421 431 441 451 461 471 481 491 501 511 521 531
 541 551 561 571 581 591 601 611 621 631 641 651 661 671 681 691 701 711
 721 731 741 751 761 771 781 791 801 811 821 831 841 851 861 871 881 891
 901 911 921 931 941 951 961 971 981 991]
base_estimator__min_samples_split [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
base_estimator__min_samples_leaf [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
base_estimator__max_leaf_nodes [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
base_estimator__min_weight_fraction_leaf [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
base_estimator__max_features [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
base_estimator__max_depth [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27]
```

Quiet Strange as I was able to get the result without any error earlier in the same code

Comment: try `BDT_param_grid1.items()`

Comment: @meW BDT_param_grid1.items() and BDT_param_grid1.keys() works

Comment: @meW Some issue with my jupyter notebook, it worked after I shutdown the kernel and restarted again

Comment: sounds good....